# Javascript conditional statement returning wrong output

Tags: javascript

Below is my function for checking and preventing to input a value greater than the available quantity. It is triggered by onBlur.

Suppose:
intData = 7
intOnHand = 46

When it reaches `if(intData > intOnHand)` it enters the code. Which supposedly it should not. Because 7 > 46 is false. Weirdly enough this happen only when input data is between 5-9. And greater than 46(which is correct).

Output of my alert: 
intData7
inOnHand46
Qty to Borrow Must not greater than the qty on the inventory!

```
function CheckInput(intData){

      var mode = $('#mode').val();

      intOnHand = $('#qtyin').html();
      if(mode == 'Borrow'){
           if(intData > intOnHand){
               alert("intData"+intData);
               alert("inOnHand"+intOnHand);
                alert("Qty to Borrow Must not greater than the qty on the inventory!");
                $("#QtyToReturn").val(intOnHand);

           }
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are doing a string comparison because `intOnHand` is of type string, convert that to a numerical type before the comparison

```
function CheckInput(intData) {

    var mode = $('#mode').val();

    var intOnHand = +$('#qtyin').html();
    if (mode == 'Borrow') {
        if (+intData > intOnHand) {
            alert("intData" + intData);
            alert("inOnHand" + intOnHand);
            alert("Qty to Borrow Must not greater than the qty on the inventory!");
            $("#QtyToReturn").val(intOnHand);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try casting it.